# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Security Certificates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

My spring boot application is calling a number  of external soap services. When I run the app in my local machine , I am required to install all the security certificates in my JVM using keytool command. However when I deploy my app to pivotal cloud foundry platform , the app is not complaining about the security certificates. The services that I consume are primarily hosted in weblogic clusters running on different data centers.Is there a possible explanation as to why the app deployed in pcf platform is not asking for security certificates to be installed? Could these have been installed by pcf admin when they made the java buildpack available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your system administrator will need to add the trusted certificate to Cloud Foundry, the process is slightly different dependent on whether it's open source CF or Pivotal CF:

OSS CF: http://bosh.io/docs/trusted-certs.html

Pivotal CF : https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/devguide/deploy-apps/trusted-system-certificates.html

Once the certificate is added, it's just a matter of telling the java buildpack to trust that certificate, you can do that by setting an environment variable on the app itself:

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/buildpacks/java/bosh_custom_trusted_certs.html

Comment: If you could accept my answer, that would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Sorry , I was asked to wait 4 minutes before I accept. And I forgot. Thank you!

Comment: @Dan For Pivotal CF can you provide how the folder directories would look like? I am confused.